# Remove All Unnecessary Whitespaces from JSON String with regex (in AutoHotKey)

Tags: json, regex, autohotkey, minify

How do I remove ALL **unnecessary** white-spaces from a JSON String (in AutoHotkey)?

I assume that I need to use **regExReplace** with some clever **regex** in order to NOT touch the white-spaces that are part of the values.

*A simple example would be:*

**Before:**

```
g_config := 
{ 
    FuzzySearch:{
        enable: true,
        keysMAXperEntry : 6,
        o = {
            keyString: "Hello World"
        }
    }
} ;
```

**After:** `g_config:={FuzzySearch:{enable:true,keysMAXperEntry:6,o={keyString:"Hello World"}}};`

Basically, I'm looking for a way to minify and pack the string as tight as possible without changing any data.

first I tried searching `[\n]+` and replace with "" (nothing). Developed here:

> https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106988 
>   the same here
>   https://regex101.com/r/dZnHaZ/1

## Best try: Then I reused this

> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1230349/Remove-extra-space-in-json-string 
>   to:
>   https://regex101.com/r/EYFHy9/4

**Problem: this regEx also removes the spaces in a value.**
Is it even better to do?

Comment: Can't you just read the JSON and write it back without intermediate whitespaces?

Comment: @tobias_k It is possible that the values ​​themselves contain spaces

Comment: Exactly, and those would not be affected by that. Much harder when using regex.

Comment: BTW; you are aware that that's not valid JSON, right?

Comment: I believe AHK can run JavaScript code ; if that's true, to minimize JSON you would want to run the following JS code : `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(yourJson))`. Of course that would raise an error for data that isn't valid JSON, such as your sample input.

Comment: Re:"not valid JSON" Oh, I did not notice that. my script recognizes it. Oops

Comment: Parsing a complex recursive structured language with regex is a recipe for madness. I'll take as testament the fact that in your current best-try regex, only the `\s+` alternative has any effect, the first alternative being little more than gibberish. You should try to find a parser for your data format whatever it is, or write one yourself if it is a custom format

Comment: ried `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(s))` without success. screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/9BJK8kA

Comment: @SL5net "Without success" So, what happened? Function not available, invalid JSON, or result not as desired? The screenshot does not really show much.

Comment: I couldn't write AHK code to save my life, but the parser should go something like this : what is current char? if it's a space, am I inside quotes? If not a space or inside quotes, output it (otherwise don't). if it's quotes and the previous character isn't an escape, I am now inside quotes if I wasn't previously, and conversely

Comment: I gave up looking for a perfect solution with only regex. i replace `"m)[\n\r]+(?![a-z]+[_\d]*)"`. implemented here as example: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/b2639f81db51526980d4a121a3ccc5d6
removes all line breaks that are not before the first variablename at the beginning of a line (in other words in the value range).

Comment: @Aaron yes I understand your algorithm. a soluteion that undstands boundaries, delimiters. a solution like here (but this is written in PHP): https://github.com/sl5net/SL5_preg_contentFinder/blob/master/tests/PHPUnit/Callback_Test.php#L277

Comment: @tobias_k Re:"Without success": There was no error. Just an empty result. No "Function not available" no "invalid JSON". Therfor the screenshot does not really show much. I interpreted that as its not working with `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(s))`

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what @Aaron mentioned, here is some slow-as-hell AHK code that will look at each individual character and remove it if it's a space or line break, except between quotes. It starts at your cursor and ends once there is nothing left to copy (or rather, one second after).

```
;;; For speed? Maybe?? ...It's still slow  :(
ListLines Off
SetBatchLines , -1
SetKeyDelay , -1 , -1
SetMouseDelay , -1
SetDefaultMouseSpeed , 0
SetWinDelay , -1
SetControlDelay , -1
SendMode , Input

f1::
Loop
{
    clipboard := ""
    Send , +{right}^c
    ClipWait , 1
    If ErrorLevel
        Break
    bT := ( clipboard = """" ) ? !bT : bT
    Send , % ( !bT && ( clipboard = "`r`n" || clipboard = A_Space  || clipboard = A_Tab )) ? "{del}" : "{right}"
}
Return
```